# Calling an extension method statically throws MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, missingmethodexception

I have an extension method that splits a set of items into smaller subsets:

```
static class MyClass {
    /// <summary>
    /// Breaks a list of items into chunks of a specific size
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunksize)
    {
        while (source.Any())
        {
            yield return source.Take(chunksize);
            source = source.Skip(chunksize);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I may call this method either via

- `MyClass.chunk(myEnumerable, 500)`, or by using
- `myEnumerable.chunk(200)`

Right? But one of my customer complains about a `MissingMethodException` when I use the static (the first) call:

> *`System.MissingMethodException`: Method not found: `System.Collections.Generic.List´1<System.Collections.Generic.List´1<!!0>> MyClass.chunk(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable´1<!!0>, Int32)`.).*

I'm not able no reproduce it, maybe with your help I may...

Comment: I think this a dlls problem and not a logical problem, make sure that the user deployed the latest dll in the correct place

Comment: There is no difference between the two ways of calling, the former is just syntactic sugar for the latter. If your cuswtomer is getting a missing method exception then it suggests his code is executing against an older version of the DLL without the method, but is compiling against a newer version with the method.

Comment: @stakx I did not want miracles, I just asked for an idea how I may reproduce this issue before, so I may give some further information. However your answer already gave me some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you notice that your method returns a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>`, but the error message is talking about a method returning a `List<List<T>>`?

If I would have to guess, I'd say that you've changed the return type of your extension method at some point. You then replaced only the DLL containing your extension method, and now some other, dependent DLL is trying to invoke your extension method as it used to be... but it's of course no longer there.

You'll have to recompile & re-deploy all assemblies that reference / invoke your extension method.

P.S.: Whether you invoke your extension method via `MyClass.chunk(myEnumerable, 500)` or via `myEnumerable.chunk(200)` does not make any difference at all; the latter style of calling an extension method is a syntactic shortcut for the former, the C# compiler will automatically transform extension method calls into the static method call it really is.

Comment: Obviously it was an issue on some old library not having been updated. Indeed the return type of the method was List before and has been changed to `IEnumerable`. Thanks for the help